# How to access one model Schema in another model mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas one is user schema in user.js file and other is product schema in product.js file

**My user schema in user.js file as follows:**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mobileno: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    facebookid: {
        type: String
    },
    userimage: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

and I am overriding automatically generated _id using mongoose-auto-increment module to get automatically incremented userId in user collection.

**And my product schema in product.js file as follows:**

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    prodcutImage: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

When user will add new products in collection he will fill all the fields mentioned in product schema. I want to verify that entered userId is exists in user collection or not when new product is added by user in product collection.
I tried to access userSchema.find method in productSchema pre save hook

```
productSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    userSchema.findOne({'_id': userId}, function(err, user)
    {
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

But It returns an error. Can somebody help me in this issue.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: see the proper error and post..what do you mean by i think.????

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
      userSchema.findOne({'_id': userId}, function(err, user)
    {
        if(user){
           next()
               }else{
                    res.json("user id is not valid");
                    }
    });      
    }, function (req, res, next) {
      // code to add your product in product schema
    })
```

more better way is to use Router-level middleware of express